# Carrinho de compras não deixa adicionar mais itens após limpa-lo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estou fazendo um carrinho de compras para um teste de E-commerce em ASP.NET MVC, trabalhando com o EF6. Estava fazendo a lógica, o carrinho ele adiciona produtos e também remove. Porém, toda vez que eu adiciono vários produtos, e então removo todos, ele não deixa mais adicionar nenhum. O problema me parece estar no objeto `Session["carrinho"]` que não retorna `null` quando todos os itens foram removidos. Segue os métodos responsáveis pelo gerenciamento do carrinho:

**Método de Adicionar:**

```
public ActionResult Compra(int id)
    {
        if(Session["carrinho"] == null)
        {
            List<Item> carrinho = new List<Item>();
            var produtos = db.produto.Find(id);
            carrinho.Add(new Item()
            {
                produto = produtos,
                Quantidade = 1
            });
            Session["carrinho"] = carrinho;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Item> carrinho = (List<Item>)Session["carrinho"];
            var produtos = db.produto.Find(id);
            foreach(var item in carrinho)
            {
                if(item.produto.CodBarra == id)
                {
                    int qtd = item.Quantidade;
                    carrinho.Remove(item);
                    carrinho.Add(new Item()
                    {
                        produto = produtos,
                        Quantidade = qtd+1
                    });
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    carrinho.Add(new Item()
                    {
                        produto = produtos,
                        Quantidade = 1
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
            Session["carrinho"] = carrinho;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Método de Remover:**

```
public ActionResult RemoverProd(int id)
    {
        List<Item> carrinho = (List<Item>)Session["carrinho"];
        var produtos = db.produto.Find(id);
        foreach (var item in carrinho)
        {
            if(item.produto.CodBarra == id)
            {
                carrinho.Remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }
        Session["carrinho"] = carrinho;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Gostaria de receber ajuda para conseguir resolver esse problema

Comment: não vou entrar muito no merito do seu código mas se você quiser comportar uma lista vazia você poderia simplesmente colocar uma nova condição no seu if além de checar apenas pra null, por exemplo: if(Session["carrinho"] == null || !((List<Item>)Session["carrinho"]).Any())

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, agora consigo adicionar itens mesmo zerando o carrinho.